# My app title disapears when add ScrollView

Tags: scrollview, titlebar

So when i putt ScrollView above an LinearLayout my app title disapeare and my first text view come to place of app title so what am i going to do to fix it,But when i delete scroll view above LinearLayout then it works fine

here is my code below
thanks!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical">
```